# Where we can see the mounted directory on host when "emptyDir" volume with "medium: Memory" is used in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I used volume with these configuration in kubernetes:

```
emptyDir:
  medium: Memory
```

How to dynamically/programatically figure out the host path on the nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir):

> By default, emptyDir volumes are stored on whatever medium is backing
>   the node - that might be disk or SSD or network storage, depending on
>   your environment. However, you can set the emptyDir.medium field to
>   "Memory" to tell Kubernetes to mount a tmpfs (RAM-backed filesystem)
>   for you instead. While tmpfs is very fast, be aware that unlike disks,
>   tmpfs is cleared on node reboot and any files you write will count
>   against your Container’s memory limit.

If I understand you correctly (and by `host path` you doesn't mean [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)) you can simply execute `# df -h` which will display how much disk space is available in a human readable form. Also showing:

- Filesystem (in your case `tmpfs`)
- Size
- Used
- Available
- Use%
- Mounted on

It's worth noting that the default size of a RAM-based `emptyDir` is half the RAM of the node it runs on.

Please let me know if that helps.